# Issue with setDoc() and updateDoc() when using "if" "else"

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

I have this issue and can't figure out how to solve it, addDoc() and setDoc() functions separately without using "if" "else" work correctly, but when I use "if" "else" it gives me this error.

"Error adding product to cart:  TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'quantity')"

It is a function to add a product to the cart, it must check if the document is already in the subcollection, then increase quantity +1, otherwise create a document, taking the name of the product as the document id.

I'am using Vue.js 3 and Firebase 9.

```
const productRef = doc(db, "carts", cartId, "cartProducts", this.productName);
                        const productDoc = await getDoc(productRef);
    
                        if (productDoc.exists) {
                            await updateDoc(productRef, {
                                quantity: productDoc.data().quantity + 1
                            });
                            
                        } else {
                            await setDoc(productRef, product);
                        }
```

Answer (score 1):

The error

> Error adding product to cart: TypeError: Cannot read properties of
> undefined (reading 'quantity')

indicates that the field `quantity` is undefined in the `productDoc`.

So either you enforce through security rules that `quantity` has a correct value when the `productDoc` doc is created/updated or you adapt your code to handle this case as follows, for example:

```
const productRef = doc(db, "carts", cartId, "cartProducts", this.productName);
const productDoc = await getDoc(productRef);
console.log(JSON.stringify(productDoc.data()));
if (productDoc.exists && productDoc.data().quantity) {
    await updateDoc(productRef, {
        quantity: productDoc.data().quantity + 1
    });

} else {
    await setDoc(productRef, product);
}
```

Comment: unfortunately it gives me the same error

Comment: Can you add `console.log(JSON.stringify(productDoc.data()));` as shown in the updated answer? Also are you sure that the vue.js method is `async`?

Comment: Solved using runTransaction

Answer (score 0):

solved using runTransaction

```
import { runTransaction } from "firebase/firestore";
const productRef = doc(db, "carts", cartId, "cartProducts", this.productName);

                    try {
                        await runTransaction(db, async (transaction) => {
                            const newQ = await transaction.get(productRef);
                            if (!newQ.exists()) {
                                await setDoc(productRef, product);
                                throw " Document no exist ";
                            }
                            const newQuant = newQ.data().quantity + 1;
                            transaction.update(productRef, { quantity: newQuant });

                        });
                        console.log("Transaction successfully committed!");
                    } catch (e) {
                        console.log("Transaction failed: ", e);
                    }
```